# Multiple childs not working in firebase database in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an e commerce app that should put the products he ordered in the firebase database when the user clicks the checkout button.I added code for that:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            confirm();

        }
    });
}

public void confirm() {
    productprice = getView().findViewById(R.id.productTotalPriceTextView);
    productname=getView().findViewById(R.id.productNameTextView);

    final String saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime;

    Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calForDate.getTime());



    spinner=getView().findViewById(R.id.quantitySpinner);

    String productPrice =productprice.getText().toString();
    String productN=productname.getText().toString();
    String productq= CartItem.getSelectedSpinnerValue(spinner,quantity);

    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString().trim();

    cartholder op = new cartholder(productPrice,productq,productN, saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime);

    FirebaseDatabase dab = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference note = dab.getReference("Products");

    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);
    note.child(productN).setValue(op);

    Intent intent = new Intent(CartFragment.this.getActivity(), CheckoutActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finishActivity();
}
```

**cartholder.java**

```
package com.example.shoppingcart;

public class cartholder {
    String productPrice, productq, productN, Time, Date;

    public cartholder(String productPrice, String productq, String productN, String time, String date) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.productq = productq;
        this.productN = productN;
        Time = time;
        Date = date;
    }

    public String getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(String productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductq() {
        return productq;
    }

    public void setProductq(String productq) {
        this.productq = productq;
    }

    public String getProductN() {
        return productN;
    }

    public void setProductN(String productN) {
        this.productN = productN;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        Time = time;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

but when I order 3 or more products in the firebase there shows only two products.For example:

[image: This Image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the content of those products in the database.

Comment: I have updated you can check

Comment: What do you mean by "put the products he ordered"?

Comment: I mean when the user adds the product to cart and clicks the checkout button the products in the cart should go to the firebase realtime database.

Comment: Are you sure that all three products have different names?

Comment: Yes they all have different names

Comment: Then why do you say that only two are added?

Comment: Look there are a total of twelve products in the app and if I order 3 or more products it adds two or one products in firebase database others are not added.